# error while auto downloading a report through selenium and python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I'm doing automation of a website and auto downloading a report through `selenium` and `python` and I get this error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>
C:\Python27\python.exeC:\Python27\Scripts\MH_Download3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\MH_Download3.py", line 111, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__self.binary, timeout)
File`"C:\Python27\lib\sitepackages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\sitepackages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 67, in launch_browserself._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\sitepackages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 90, in _start_from_profile_path env=self._firefox_env)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__ errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Please edit your question

Comment: Where's your code?  Please see [Ask].  You also didn't even bother to take the 2-minute site [tour].